# How do I convert non-normal distribution to a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have the below graph I drew using histogram in Excel but when I got my data and graphed it, certainly it is not a normal distribution. My assignment required me to gather some data and draw normal distributions and confidence intervals etc but I don't know what to do because my graph is not a normal distribution?

Should I fabricate some data to create a normal distribution or is there a legit way to create the normal distribution from this data? I read from a Google search there is Box-Cox transformation to create a normal distribution from non-normal data but being in a beginner stats class as an engineer I don't have that level of knowledge to achieve that.

Please help. Here is what my graphs look like:

[image]

If I should create data to resemble a normal distribution then how do I generate random data for each histogram range with a frequency to generate a sample set with normal distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the data does not appear normally distributed.  If you are restricted to using the existing data then you might take small sub-samples and calculate the averages. The distribution of this average should appear more like a normal distribution -- as per the central limit theorem.

If you want to generate some new normally distributed data, you can use the random number generator in Excel.  Generate some uniformly distributed random numbers using the RAND() function, then apply the inverse normal distribution to each one -- NORMSINV(). Then you will have a sample from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  If you want a mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then transform as $x \mapsto\mu+ \sigma x.$

Comment: I will try to re-sample the data and if I keep getting non-normal distributions then I will do the sub sampling approach you recommended. Thank you

Comment: If you generate enough new data with the random number generator it will definately look normal.  You're welcome.